# Why I can't correctly perform a JOIN between 2 tables having a common field?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I am pretty new in SQL and I have the following problem trying to perform this query:

```
SELECT count(distinct intervento.prg_int)
from TID023_INTERVENTO intervento,
     TID025_SITUAZIONEDOCUMENTALE situazioneDocumentale 
INNER JOIN TID018_ENTEBENEFICIARIO enteBeneficiario
    ON(enteBeneficiario.COD_ENT = intervento.COD_ENT)
INNER JOIN anagrafiche.TPG1029_PROVNUOIST provNuovIst
    ON (provNuovIst.COD_PRV_NIS = enteBeneficiario.COD_PRV_NIS)
WHERE situazioneDocumentale.PRG_INT = intervento.PRG_INT
  AND situazioneDocumentale.FLG_STO = 0
  AND intervento.COD_TIP_BAN = 1
  and situazioneDocumentale.COD_STA_DOC in(2,3)
  AND provNuovIst.COD_REG = "LO";
```

As you can see I am trying to perform a **JOIN** between the **TID018_ENTEBENEFICIARIO enteBeneficiario** and the **TID023_INTERVENTO intervento** tables.

Both these tables contain the **COD_ENT** field (that is primary key into the **TID018_ENTEBENEFICIARIO enteBeneficiario** table and foreign keyinto the **TID023_INTERVENTO intervento**).

The problem is that, performing this query, I obtain this error message:

> **Unknown column 'intervento.COD_ENT' in 'on clause'**

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Scope issue. Explicit joins are evaluated before comma separated tables.

Comment: Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ever mix up explicit and implicit join syntax's and generally avoid the use of implicit syntax, I don't even know whats suppose to happen in this case.. Try this query:

```
SELECT count(distinct intervento.prg_int)
from TID023_INTERVENTO intervento
INNER JOIN TID025_SITUAZIONEDOCUMENTALE situazioneDocumentale 
    ON(situazioneDocumentale.PRG_INT = intervento.PRG_INT)
INNER JOIN TID018_ENTEBENEFICIARIO enteBeneficiario
    ON(enteBeneficiario.COD_ENT = intervento.COD_ENT)
INNER JOIN anagrafiche.TPG1029_PROVNUOIST provNuovIst
    ON (provNuovIst.COD_PRV_NIS = enteBeneficiario.COD_PRV_NIS)
WHERE situazioneDocumentale.FLG_STO = 0
  AND intervento.COD_TIP_BAN = 1
  and situazioneDocumentale.COD_STA_DOC in(2,3)
  AND provNuovIst.COD_REG = "LO";
```

I also noticed this line:

```
    INNER JOIN anagrafiche.TPG1029_PROVNUOIST provNuovIst
```

Which seems strange looking at all your other tables, is this from another schema? Or is it a typo?

Comment: Tnx, yes the "anagrafiche.TPG1029_PROVNUOIST provNuovIst" is from another schema

Comment: No problem :) @AndreaNobili

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that not all the tables in the FROM clause are joined in different ways, and therefore in a different order.  To fix this, be more consistent with the different joins, such as:

```
SELECT count(distinct intervento.prg_int)
FROM TID023_INTERVENTO intervento
JOIN TID025_SITUAZIONEDOCUMENTALE situazioneDocumentale
    ON(intervento.PRG_INT = situazioneDocumentale.PRG_INT)
INNER JOIN TID018_ENTEBENEFICIARIO enteBeneficiario
    ON(enteBeneficiario.COD_ENT = intervento.COD_ENT)
INNER JOIN anagrafiche.TPG1029_PROVNUOIST provNuovIst
    ON (provNuovIst.COD_PRV_NIS = enteBeneficiario.COD_PRV_NIS)
WHERE situazioneDocumentale.FLG_STO = 0
  AND intervento.COD_TIP_BAN = 1
  AND situazioneDocumentale.COD_STA_DOC in(2,3)
  AND provNuovIst.COD_REG = "LO";
```

Good luck!